# Multi-level list formatting in css. Display horizontally or vertically depending on list item class

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using wordpress for developping a website and I added the main menu of my site in the footer. I'd like to format the list in the following way, so I need to use custom css :

```
Page 1      Page 2                          Page 3      Page 4      Page 5
Page 1.1    Page 2.1 (bold) Page 2.2 (bold) Page 3.1    Page 4.1
Page 1.2    Page 2.1.1      Page 2.2.1      Page 3.2    Page 4.2
Page 1.3    Page 2.1.2      Page 2.2.2      Page 3.3
Page 1.4    Page 2.1.3      Page 2.2.3      Page 3.4
Page 1.5    Page 2.1.4      Page 2.2.4      Page 3.5
                                            Page 3.6
```

To sum up :

- First-level list should be displayed horizontally
- Second-level list should be displayed vertically, except if some list elements have children. Those should be displayed horizontally and use a bold fond.
- Third-level list should be displayed vertically below their parent
  second-level item.

My wordpress theme generates the html code and gives a specific class for a list item which has some children (class='menu-item-has-children'), so with the right css selectors, I should be able to do it, but I didn't find how to.

Here is my code : https://jsfiddle.net/aqt9vw4u/

Could anyone please explain me how to format my list that way.

Answer (score 0):

First things first you need to reorganize your lists to all be using the same hierarchy. Since you're going to have certain lists having sublists, they all need to be setup the same regardless of whether they have sublists. Then once you've fixed that, it's a matter of listing them certain directions which is done easiest using flexbox. Since this is wordpress, your template should be able to tell if a list has children, and then echo a header or not.

https://jsfiddle.net/aqt9vw4u/3/

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-4578"><a href="#">Page 1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-number" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-no-children menu-item-number">
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-4357" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2783 current_page_item menu-item-4357"><a>Page 1.1</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-4358" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4358"><a>Page 1.2</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-4365" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4365"><a>Page 1.3</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-4359" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4359"><a>Page 1.4</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-4360" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4360"><a>Page 1.5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

By changing your other lists to be structured like your second list that has sub-sub lists you can accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This menu is also used as main navigation menu in my header bar, so I can't change it. I could duplicate the menu and have a different one for the footer, but I'd rather avoid this solution.
I thought that this class attribute was given to be able to deal with this type of situation, and give a special formatting to those items which have children.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to modify a parent based on its child using pure CSS. You would need to use JS for this. Sorry I couldn't help more!

Comment: Thanks again. You are probably right. I manage to achieve better results thanks to your example. Here is the current state :
https://jsfiddle.net/aqt9vw4u/4/
I'll leave it like that if I can't find a better solution.